# Download multiple images to folder using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, download, imagedownload

I created a webpage that fetches image urls using an external api and then displays them on the page.  Now i want the end user to be able to download these images all at once.  Since these images do not exist on my sites server, i am looking for a way to do this via javascript/jquery.

I was able to do this in chrome using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830088/download-multiple-images-at-once-with-javascript)  and would like a way to prompt firefox and other browsers to do the same.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have access to the clients filesystem, nor can you add multiple files like that to the file download dialog etc.

Comment: I understand that completely.  Maybe there is a way to prompt the browser to do it?  Possibly do a browser/version check and then do some hack?

Comment: for(loop on fetched_img urls){open(fetched_img_url,"_blank")}

Comment: @vinayakj wont that just open a bunch of new tabs, all with a single image displayed?

Comment: var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.download = "export.xls";
            link.href = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc6a0c03b68", "_blank";
            link.click();

Comment: you can use a downloader script to grab them all. note that chrome will ask the user for perms to download the 2nd one, and if they agree, the rest will flood in. the alternate is zipping them up into one download. i like https://github.com/rndme/download, but i'm biased...

Comment: @dandavis this looks promising, i will give it a try.  I did want to zip them up originally but most relied on the images being local to the server.  Thanks!

Comment: you can zip them in js: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/