# Download array of images on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, django, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a very basic html block, which has a `button` to download:

```
<div id="getImageWrapper">
    <div class="image">
        <p class="image-name">{{imageName}}</p>
        <button class="download-btn" @click="getImage">Download image/s</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `getImage()` function of the download button fetches an array of image list from the server.

```
getImage() {
    const getImagesUrl = this.$store.state.website + '/api/get-requested-user-Images/';
    this.$http.get(getImagesUrl)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

Response data from the server looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "image": "/media/1492960503_66.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "image": "/media/1492963100_0.jpeg"
  }
]
```

My problem is what to do next so that this array of images is downloaded into the user's device (not as a single zipped file, but as separate single image files) which would work in most browsers? If it helps, I am using Django as the backend and Vuejs for the front-end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download multiple images at once with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830088/download-multiple-images-at-once-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can't zip all images in JavaScript. For zipping files, you should do it in your backend ([see post for zipping on fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881294/django-create-a-zip-of-multiple-files-and-make-it-downloadable)) and then you can make it downloadable from the browser.